# issue calling a javascript function inside razor if statement

Tags: c#, javascript, html, razor, view

What i would like to do is i have 2 selector boxes set up in a view one selector holds my different profile sources.  the second one holds the profile names based on the source you selected.

My issue is i want a certain value that is put in the database to be tested against the profile source so i pull the correct profiles based on source selected.

this is where I am currently with the view:

```
    <div class="managerField">
        <label for="Source Selector" class="label">Select Source:</label>
        <select name="SourceSelector" form="PostScheduler" class="select-style" onchange="sourceSelect(this.value)">
            <option value="" selected>Please Select Source</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="managerField">
        <label for="ProfileSelector" class="label">Select Profile:</label>
        <!-- POPULATE BASED ON SOURCE SELECTED -->
        <select name="Profile Selector" class="select-style">
            @foreach (var p in Model.SocialProfiles.Where(pr => pr.SocialProfileTypeID == sourceSelect(SourceSelector))
            {
            <option value="@p.SocialProfileID">@p.ScreenName</option> 
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    @section Scripts
    {

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sourceSelect(el)
            {
                if (el == "") return 0; // Will need to catch
                if (el == "1") return 2;
                if (el == "2") return 6;
                if (el == "3") return 15;
            }
    }
```

any help would be awesomely appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run it now? If you change the `return` statements to `console.log` what is the output? This kind of looks fine to me, so it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: are you saying that within your script tag your if statement is a Razor if and not javascript if. What is the output html (view source in browser) of the script part?

Comment: Oh, you're trying to use a JavaScript function within a Razor statement.  That won't work.  Razor is a view engine.  It just emits the document (HTML, JavaScript, etc.) but it has no access to actual JavaScript code. You need to either load both lists and change the display on the client or make AJAX calls to get the appropriate list based on the first selection made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuck actually hit it on the head you can't call javascript inside of razor, i developed a new method on click to call it through JS and did away with razor.